# 'ObjectId' object has no attribute 'is_active' Flask-Login

Tags: flask, pymongo, flask-login

I'm trying to use flask-login with pymongo following the official docs and [this article](https://runningcodes.net/flask-login-and-mongodb/).
However, I can't manage to get it to work. I keep getting the error:

```
if not force and not user.is_active:
    AttributeError: 'ObjectId' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

My User class looks like this:

```
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
    def is_active(self):
        return True
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False
    def get_id(self):
        return self.user_id
    @staticmethod
    def validate_login(password_hash, password):
        return check_password_hash(password_hash, password)
```

Login manager is:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    u = db.Users.find_one({"_id": user_id})
    if not u:
        return None
    return User(u['_id'])
```

Login and signup are:

```
@auth2.route('/login', methods = ['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin()
def login():
    print("trying to login user")
    data = request.get_json()
    email = data['email']
    user = db.Users.find_one({"email": email})
    if user and User.validate_login(user['password'], data['password']):
        user_obj = User(user['_id'])
        login_user(user['_id'])
        return jsonify({"login":True})
    return "wrong Password"

@auth2.route('/signup', methods = ['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin()
def signup_user():
    print("trying to signup user")
    data = request.get_json()
    email = data['email']
    password = data['password']
    company = data['company']
    u = {'email':email}
    if email is None or password is None or company is None:
        return "missing Args.."
    if db.Users.find_one(u) is not None:
        return "User Exists"
    user = { "email": email, "password": generate_password_hash(password), "teams":[company]}
    db.Users.insert(user)
    # Login User
    new_user = db.Users.find_one({"email":email})
    login_user(new_user['_id'])
    return 'User Added and logged in', 201
```

What am I missing?
P.s. I tried also without the `(UserMixin)`
and I've tried: `class User(db.Users, UserMixin):`
But then I get:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Answer (score 1):

[`flask_login.utils.login_user`](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/0.4.1/flask_login/utils.py#L134) function should be called with an instance of `User`.

`new_user` should be hydrated and passed as an argument to it.

```
@auth2.route('/login', methods = ['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin()
def login():
    ...
    if user and User.validate_login(user['password'], data['password']):
        user_obj = User(user['_id'])
        login_user(user_obj)
        return jsonify({"login":True})
    return "wrong Password"

@auth2.route('/signup', methods = ['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin()
def signup_user():
    ...
    new_user = db.Users.find_one({"email":email})
    login_user(User(new_user['_id']))
    return 'User Added and logged in', 201
```